# Checkboxes and localStorage

Tags: javascript

I have a list of tasks if you will and I am trying to create checkboxes that persist next to each when I go back to the page but closing the browser or hard refresh kills my selections. I have found code for saving a single checkbox but how do I iterate through the different boxes and keep them next time I enter? It seems like a really simple process but I am super-new to javascript... I could do this easily in vbscript but I would like it to work everywhere and not just IE!

New to all this so be gentle please.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="whatever-1" />This task
<input type="checkbox" id="whatever-2" />This task
<input type="checkbox" id="whatever-3" />This task
<input type="checkbox" id="whatever-4" />This task
<input type="checkbox" id="whatever-5" />This task
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="save();" />
```

```js
// then enter variation of the code I found here
<script >
  function save() {
    //enter iteration sequence
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("box");
    localStorage.setItem("box", checkbox.checked);
  }

//for loading...
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("box"));
document.getElementById("box").checked = checked; <
/script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why not try something? You're currently dealing with only one box. Your comment even points to what you need to do - "enter iteration sequence". That is, you need to iterate over the checkboxes in a loop and build up a collection of values to save.

Comment: You can do a for loop and do `document.getElementById("whatever-" +i) etc.

Comment: Are you trying to use `localStorage` in pages loaded from a local driver using the `file://` protocol? _This doesn't work in Microsoft browsers, IE or Edge which only support `localStorage` in pages from a server._  It does work in Chrome or Firefox that I know of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To retrieve all elements you can use `document.querySelectorAll`  and pass as argument the filter that will do the job. In this case you want to retrieve all `htlm` elements that have the `type` attribute value equals to `checkbox`.  After the retrieval of all elements that have `type="checkbox"`, you  should traverse all elements of list. And for each element you should store the id of checkbox as `key` and the `checked`  of the checkbox as`value` in localstorage.

Below is the code:

```
    <script>
        save = function(){
            var list = document.querySelectorAll(`[type*="checkbox"]`);
            list.forEach( el => {
                localStorage.setItem(el.id, el.checked);
                console.log(el.id,el.checked);
            })

        }
    </script>
```

And below is the code for updating the checkboxes with value we stored in localstorage.

```
            var list = document.querySelectorAll(`[type*="checkbox"]`);
            list.forEach( el => {
            var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(el.id));
            document.getElementById(el.id).checked = checked;
            });
```

If you want to use cookie to store the information instead of local storage. Link for more information: https://www.guru99.com/cookies-in-javascript-ultimate-guide.html.

```
function createCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, daysToExpire) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (daysToExpire * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
}

function accessCookie(cookieName) {
    var name = cookieName + "=";
    var allCookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < allCookieArray.length; i++) {
        var temp = allCookieArray[i].trim();
        if (temp.indexOf(name) == 0)
            return temp.substring(name.length, temp.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

VERSION WITH LOCAL STORAGE

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-1" />This task
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-2" />This task
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-3" />This task
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-4" />This task
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-5" />This task
        <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="save();" />
    </div>
        <script>
            window.onload= function(){
                    var list = document.querySelectorAll(`[type*="checkbox"]`);
                    list.forEach( el => {
                        var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(el.id));
                        document.getElementById(el.id).checked = checked;
                    });
            }
            save = function(){
            var list = document.querySelectorAll(`[type*="checkbox"]`);
            list.forEach( el => {
                localStorage.setItem(el.id, el.checked);
                console.log(el.id,el.checked);
            })

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

VERSION WITH COOKIE

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-1" />This task
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-2" />This task
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-3" />This task
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-4" />This task
        <input type="checkbox" id="whatever-5" />This task
        <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="save();" />
    </div>
        <script>
            window.onload= function(){
                    var list = document.querySelectorAll(`[type*="checkbox"]`);
                    list.forEach( el => {
                        var checked = JSON.parse(accessCookie(el.id));
                        document.getElementById(el.id).checked = checked;
                    });
            }
            save = function(){
                var list = document.querySelectorAll(`[type*="checkbox"]`);
                list.forEach( el => {
                    createCookie(el.id, el.checked,1);//1 is the day to expire
                    console.log(el.id,el.checked);
                })
            }
            function createCookie(cookieName, cookieValue, daysToExpire) {
                var date = new Date();
                date.setTime(date.getTime() + (daysToExpire * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            }

            function accessCookie(cookieName) {
                var name = cookieName + "=";
                var allCookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < allCookieArray.length; i++) {
                    var temp = allCookieArray[i].trim();
                    if (temp.indexOf(name) == 0)
                        return temp.substring(name.length, temp.length);
                }
                return "";
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This worked beautifully and saved the checks until I uploaded it from my local machine to the internet. Now it doesn't work. Would it make more sense to set a cookie? If so, I would have no idea how to even begin that process in javascript! Arrgh!

Comment: window.onclick=save;
        function save<br>(){
            var list = document.querySelectorAll<br>(`[type*="checkbox"]`);
            list.forEach<br>( el => {
                localStorage.setItem<br>(el.id, el.checked);
                console.log<br>(el.id,el.checked);
            })

        }


     var list = document.querySelectorAll<br>(`[type*="checkbox"]`);
            list.forEach<br>( el => {
            var checked = JSON.parse<br>(localStorage.getItem<br>(el.id));
            document.getElementById<br>(el.id).checked = checked;
            });

Comment: I apologize. I am really botching the formatting here. How do you paste just a single frame of code?

Comment: If you want to use cookies to store the information. Here is link that will help you how to use the cookies. https://www.guru99.com/cookies-in-javascript-ultimate-guide.html

Comment: I made some modification if you want to use the cookie. I think it makes sense to use cookie because you want the server remember some activity done by the client.                                                                                                               "Cookies are data, stored in small text files, on your computer.When a web server has sent a web page to a browser, the connection is shut down, and the server forgets everything about the user.Cookies were invented to solve the problem how to remember information about the user"

Comment: I think I am getting something wrong here, because it is not working.  Probably a screw up on my part because Javascript is super-finicky about punctuation!  I have uploaded the final product (too big to put here) to my site at https://ffxlife.com/capcheck.html (go ahead and joke about how this is super useless!)  If you could take a look at the code and let me know where I am going wrong, that would be awesome.

Comment: substitue ```createCookie(el.id, el.checked, daysToExpire) {``` with ```createCookie(el.id, el.checked, 1);```. Test it and tell me if it worked.

Comment: Also I dont see ```             var list = document.querySelectorAll(`[type*="checkbox"]`);
            list.forEach( el => {
            var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(el.id));
            var checked = JSON.parse(accessCookie(el.id));
            document.getElementById(el.id).checked = checked;
            }); ``` added. This is important. You need to added it.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you lost me.  Maybe I am entering it into the wrong place?  I have all these snippets from you and I think I am getting confused.

Comment: I have created two snippet VERSION WITH LOCAL STORAGE and VERSION WITH COOKIE. I tested them. You just need to copy the code and paste it in your html file. I hope it helps you. You can use https://jsfiddle.net/ if you want to test it quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a different id in to `document.getElementById`. 
Make sure to use a different key for `localStorage.setItem` so you don't overwrite a different value.

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("whatever-1");
localStorage.setItem("whatever-1", checkbox.checked);
```

```
var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("whatever-1"));
document.getElementById("whatever-1").checked = checked;
```

---

You could do this individually for each item or you could get all the elements of a specific class. Then loop through the elements and use their id as the local storage key.

---

Alternatively you could use a `for` loop and loop for as many items as you wish to save

Answer (score 0):

On every `save` you can create an object with checkbox identification and values, save t in `localStorage`, on reloading, get the the whole object by a single key, parse it, loop through and set values

```
function save() {
  //enter iteration sequence
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
  var obj = {};
  for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    obj[checkboxes[i].id] = checkboxes[i].checked
  }
  localStorage.setItem("box", JSON.stringify(obj));
}

//for loading...
var checkboxesValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("box"));
Object.keys(checkboxesValues).map(key => document.getElementById(key).checked = checkboxesValues[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well too if you pass right id's of inputs but there is an issue with it that for each and every input you have to add there variable you also can use for loop for that.

Your code with fixing script

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="whatever-1" />This task
<input type="checkbox" id="whatever-2" />This task
<input type="button" value="Save" onclick="save();" />


<script>
  function save() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("whatever-1");
    localStorage.setItem("whatever-1", checkbox.checked);
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("whatever-2");
    localStorage.setItem("whatever-2", checkbox2.checked);
  }

var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("whatever-1"));
document.getElementById("whatever-1").checked = checked; 

var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("whatever-2"));
document.getElementById("whatever-2").checked = checked; 
</script>
```